# Search only by numbers on mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

Have this problem:

I need to compare if a number exists on a mysql table, but this number on some inputs is formatted with "-" and "." but i only want to check if numbers are equal.

so far im come to this:

```
SELECT value
FROM table 
WHERE (value REGEXP '^[0-9]+$') LIKE '000';
```

000 is the number i want to see if exists on the table but without the alphabetic chacarters... it could be like 0-00 or 0.00 but i need to ignore the alphanumeric caractarters... but this query returns nothing...

i've managed to show the records like this:

```
SELECT value
FROM table 
WHERE value REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

this shows only numbers... but i need to compare.

Thank you very much!

ps: rusty english sorry ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

`select value from table where replace(replace(value, '-', ''), '.', '') = '000'`

Comment: awesome! i love stackoverflow! Thank you ;-)

Comment: Thanks, please accept the answer if it make sense to you.. ;)